# Promise is returning [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to do a basic check to see if an image is retina and has a portrait ratio. I have all that checking functionality working perfectly fine. My issue is that in the final function that is supposed to return the boolean I get from my checks it is returning `[object Promise]`. I have no idea why this is not returning my boolean when I resolve the promise.

When I run `.then(res => console.log(res))` it outputs my boolean response, but the function `getImageMeta()` that returns the promise just returns that `[object Promise]` which makes me think the promise isn't actually being resolved.

If I could get some assistance that would be great!

```
/************************************
   Check if image is retina portrait
************************************/
const checkIfPortrait = src => !isRetina(src) ? false : getImageMeta(src).then(res => res);
 const isRetina        = src => src.indexOf('@2x') !== -1;
 const isPortrait      = ({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) => naturalHeight > naturalWidth ? true : false;

 function getImageMeta (src) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return img.addEventListener("load", function () {
         return resolve(isPortrait(this));
      }, false);
    });
  }


 export { checkIfPortrait }
```

This is how I am calling the function:

```
<img src={media[i].image} alt={media[i].alt} data-portrait={checkIfPortrait(media[i].image)} />
```

Comment: Have a look at [MDN - Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) to learn more about promises. `.then(res => res)` is redundant, you don't need it. *"My issue is that in the final function that is supposed to return the boolean"* That's not possible. You cannot convert an asynchronous process into a synchronous one.

Comment: I got this error when I forgot to mention "await" besides service call in the async function. It got resolved after adding it.

Answer (score 46):

This is the expected result. When you return a `new Promise` object, it will always be a promise object (`[object Promise]` when stringified).

You access the result of a promise by using the `.then` method (or using `await` in an `async` function). Your `.then` callback is then called when/if the result is made available, which will happen after you call `resolve`, or if the promise was already resolved prior it will be called rather quickly.

```js
function getImageMeta(src) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({metadata: `for: ${src}`});
        }, 100);
    });
}

getImageMeta('test.png').then(meta => {
    console.log(meta); // {"metadata": "for: test.png"}
});

(async () => {
    const meta = await getImageMeta('test.png');
    console.log(meta); // {"metadata": "for: test.png"}
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea of a promise is that it gives you something to return right away even if it won't resolve until later. It represents its eventual value. So `getImageMeta ()` is immediately returning the promise even though it has not resolved.

Once you have the promise returned by `getImageMeta ()` you can use its `then()` to wait for the final boolean, which will come on the next event loop cycle at the earliest.

With your current code you are saving the promise returned by `getImageMeta()` to `checkIfPortrait`. So now `checkIfPortrait` holds this promise and you can call `then()` on it. Since you are exporting `checkIfPortrait` you will probably end up calling then on the module that imports it:

```
 // import checkIfPortrait
checkIfPortrait(src)
.then(ret_val => {
   //you can access boolean here in ret_val
})
```

Comment: Sorry @BradyEdgar - I see what's going on now. I didn't realize you were saving the result to checkIfPortrait and exporting that. checkIfPortrait with hold a reference to the promise. You'll call `then()` on  `checkIfPortrait`. But the way promises work you can't access the value directly because that will be too soon. You need to deal with it in the `then()` callback.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
function axiosTest() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => error);
}

async function getResponse () {
        const response = await axiosTest();
        console.log(response);
}

getResponse()
```

It works, but each function where you want to get the response needs to be an async function or use an additional `.then()` callback.

```
function axiosTest() {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .catch(error => error);
}

async function getResponse () {
        axiosTest().then(response => {
                console.log(response)
        });
}

getResponse()
```

*If anyone knows a way to avoid this please do tell.*

Also checkout **Katsiaryna (Kate) Lupachova**'s [article on Dev.to](https://dev.to/ramonak/javascript-how-to-access-the-return-value-of-a-promise-object-1bck). I think it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now resolved, thanks to everyone for the help. Like stated the issue was I was calling the promise's value before it could be resolved and had no way of updating that value after it had been resolved.

So what I did is made sure the image data was accessible before running the function. Then once I had a resolved promise it then update the image data to show whether it is portrait or not.

So the final code looks like this:

```
const enhance = lifecycle({
   componentWillMount: function () {
     Object.keys(this.props.media).map((i) =>
       checkIfPortrait(this.props.media[i].image)
         ? this.props.media[i].isPortrait = true
         : this.props.media[i].isPortrait = false
       );
   }
 })
```

---

```
const checkIfPortrait = src => !isRetina(src) ? false : getImageMeta(src).then(res => res);
 const isRetina        = src => src.indexOf('@2x') !== -1;
 const isPortrait      = ({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) => naturalHeight > naturalWidth ? true : false;

 function getImageMeta (src) {
   const img = new Image();
   img.src = src;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     return img.addEventListener("load", function () {
       return resolve(isPortrait(this));
     }, false);
   });
 }


 export { checkIfPortrait }
```

---

```
<img src={media[i].image} alt={media[i].alt} data-portrait={media[i].isPortrait} />
```

Answer (score 0):

your function return  promise so you should call it as promise

```
   <img src={media[i].image} alt={media[i].alt} data-portrait={checkIfPortrait(media[i].image).then(result=>result})};
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise is returning [object Promise] then it returns a null value.
check the collection of mongo DB and ensure accessing path is correct.