# How to fix [object Promise] in a async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get the _id of a inserted document in a Mongo database in NodeJS.

First I call the function that inserts the document

```
// First Function
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('entrys');

    var id = databaseAPI.createRecord(req, req.body.name);
    console.log("Finished " + id)
});
```

I save the return from the Second Function below in `id` but when I log it I get [object Promise]

The insert into function in a different .js file:

```
//Second Function
createRecord: async function(req, name) {
      var db = req.db;
      var collection = db.get('entrys');
      var objectToInsert = {
        Name: name
      };

      collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err){
   if (err) {
     return null;
    console.log("err");
  }
   // Object inserted successfully.
        console.log(objectToInsert._id) // This returns the ID 
     return objectToInsert._id; // This should return the ID to the first function but I get [object Promise]
```

I tried the playing around with `async` and `await` like the first answer from this question [Promise is returning [object Promise]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719974/promise-is-returning-object-promise) but if I do that I get "undefined" instead of "[object Promise]".

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Edit:

If I do `var id = await databaseAPI.createRecord(req, req.body.name)`

I get "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Now If I make the function async I get "undefined" when I `console.log` id.

Comment: Your second function is incomplete. But by looking at it, it looks like the library you are using, works with callbacks and not promises. Since you are returning the value inside the callback, it is not returned as a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should rewrite the first function to be like this (as suggested by @MrfksIV) but with a Try-catch block, so you can see the errors:

```
router.post('/add', async function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('entrys');

  try {
    var id = await databaseAPI.createRecord(req, req.body.name);
    console.log("Finished " + id)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Err: " + err);
  }
});
```

Regarding the second function, you are returning nothing in that function, that is why you get undefined. And also, in the callback, you are expecting that the `objectToInsert` will be modified by the `collection.insert` method, which is very unlikely. Probably this method will pass the inserted object to the callback.
So, I suppose you should rewrite you second function to work with the callback, like this:

```
//Second Function
createRecord: function(req, name) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('entrys');
  var objectToInsert = {
    Name: name
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    collection.insert(objectToInsert, function(err, insertedObj){
      if (err) {
        console.log("err");
        reject(err)
      } else {
        console.log(insertedObj);
        resolve(insertedObj._id);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The [mongoose callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558418/what-parameters-are-passed-to-mongoose-callbacks) follows the pattern `function(err, data)`.

Comment: With this code I get a _err_ : _UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>_ and _UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection_ . This might be a dumb question but with libarys do you mean the modules? If yes I use mongoose.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the answer.

Comment: @RjuJBong corrected the answer, it should work now. For other questions, remember to add the module you are using and the version, allowing who is trying to help you to check the documentation and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
// First Function
router.post('/add', async function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('entrys');

    var id = await databaseAPI.createRecord(req, req.body.name);
    console.log("Finished " + id)
});
```

Basically you need to call `.createRecord` with `await` in the beginning. For than to work, you need to make post handler `async` since `await` can only be used within `async` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried that. Look at my edit

Comment: The fact that you get back undefined, indicates that there is something wrong with the logic of createRecord. Try reversing the error handling logic to return null after the console.log to see what is going on - now the console.log never gets called. Better yet you can throw the error itself and try- catch it when the function is called.
Also, use createRecord = async function() instead of createRecord: async function if this is defined at the top level and not inside an object.