# Http get request URL shows [object promise]

Tags: ionic-framework, get, angular-promise

I am trying to use web api call get method to access data and display in my page. My url would be something like: `https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=xxx@gmail.com` to be able to display the data.

However, when I combine my url with a variable,it doesn't display anything and console log shows the url in `https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=[object Promise]`. Is there any way to let the url read my `this.User` variable?

please review my getUserOrder()

```
User = this.storage.get('currentUser');
constructor(private http:Http,public storage: Storage){
   
}

public getUserOrder()
{
  var url="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=";
  console.log(url+this.User);
  return this.http.get(url+this.User).map(res=>res.json());
  
}
```

I am really new to this. Pls tell me if i am unclear. Any help would be much appreciated..

**UPDATE**

It shows undefined because it accessed the variable value on top but not from ionViewWillEnter

```
User:string;
constructor(private http:Http,public storage: Storage){
   
}


async ionViewWillEnter()
{
  this.User = await this.storage.get('currentUser');
}
public getUserOrder()
{
  var url="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=";
  console.log(url+ this.User);
  return this.http.get(url+this.User).map(res=>res.json());
  
}
```

Comment: Please show how `this.User` is made/initialised

Comment: @TomasVancoillie it s saved in my ionic local storage and assigned to a variable

Comment: You should await the return of the promise `User = await this.storage.get('currentUser');`

Comment: @TomasVancoillie it shows 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should await the return of the Promise. You can do this inside the constructor or inside a lifecyle like `ionViewWillEnter()`

```js
User: string;

async ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.User = await this.storage.get('currentUser');
}
```

[Answer here: "This is the expected result."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719997/1934484)

**UPDATE**

This is a different approach: if your function is directly called somehow, you can create a function which returns the variable from storage. If the data is found, proceed with the http request.

```js
async getUserOrder() {
  const user = await this.getUserFromStorage();

  if (user) {
    var url="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder/GetUserOrder?email=";
    return this.http.get(url + user).map(res=>res.json());
  }
}

async getUserFromStorage(): Promise<string> {
  return await this.storage.get('currentUser');
}
```

Comment: it shows me an undefined.. Can u please review my updates? thanks